# Get git repo root directory, preferably with magit

Tags: magit, git

How can I get the root directory of the current git repo? I could run `shell-command-to-string` on something like `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. Is there a better way? Does `magit` or any other git front-end expose this info?

Comment: Do you mean `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` instead of `git rev-parse --git-dir`?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125637/get-the-vc-root-in-emacs-lisp

Comment: @phils Thanks! I have that same link posted in one of the comments under abo-abo's answer :)

Comment: Ah, so you did :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Magit this is available as `magit-toplevel` (but I agree with
@abo-abo that it makes sense to use `vc-root-dir`).

Comment: `vc-root-dir` is surely the most generic. However, I am unable to get it to work in that form as I mentioned in the comments on @abo-abo's answer. But this one worked straight. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You need `vc-root-dir`. Works for more than git.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't see a function or a package titled `vc-root-dir`. The only thing that's close is `vc-root-diff`. And on a `vc`-related search, I find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125637/get-the-vc-root-in-emacs-lisp).

Comment: It's an autoloaded function in vc.el, built-in

Comment: Perhaps my `vc` is too old? I have the one built-in with emacs 24.3. I don't see `vc-root` in `vc.el` or with `apropos` etc. Looking at `vc.el`, I see things like `(setq rootdir (vc-call-backend...))`. And indeed, `(vc-call-backend 'Git 'root default-directory)` works.

Comment: n.b. I think `vc-root-dir` is only in trunk at this stage. It's certainly not in 24.4. Presumably it will be available in Emacs 25.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by abo-abo, in Emacs 25, there is a function called `vc-root-dir` that does what you need in a backend-agnostic manner.  For earlier versions of Emacs, the following is a suitable replacement:

```
(defun vc-root-dir ()
  (let ((backend (vc-deduce-backend)))
    (and backend
         (ignore-errors
           (vc-call-backend backend 'root default-directory)))))
```

As mentioned by Kyle, Magit provides the function `magit-get-top-dir`, which simply calls `git rev-parse --show-cdup` and interprets the result.

Comment: Indeed, after looking at the implementation of `vc-root-diff`, I tried `vc-deduce-backend`. Somehow, that returns `nil` in my git-repo. However, `vc-responsible-backend default-directory` returns `Git`.

Comment: If the current buffer is not tracked by `vc`, then `vc-deduce-backend` returns `nil`.  Does that explain it?

Comment: Ah, it does. I was running it in `ielm` and expecting `vc-deduce-backend` to use `default-directory`. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `vc-root-dir` instead of `vc-root-diff`?